# Compiling a Python binding on Linux

Tags: python, debian, binding

I'm trying to compile a Python binding, but I'm unable to find the python.h header on debian. Which package should I install?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should install [`python-dev`](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python-dev)

Answer (score 1):

The python-dev package needs to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the header file for embedding or extending python is `Python.h`, with an uppercase P.  Linux is case sensitive, and python.h won't work.

On debian and debian deriviatives like ubuntu, you can use apt-file to find out what package to install, given a filename:

```
$ apt-file search Python.h
...
python2.6-dbg: /usr/include/python2.6_d/Python.h
python2.6-dev: /usr/include/python2.6/Python.h
...
```

Comment: or, if you don't have `apt-file` installed, the web interface at packages.debian.org: http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_contents

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the development header. try

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install python2.6-dev
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
```

According to virtualenv option